# VSIX - How to include XML documentation files in package?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsixmanifest

I've found the following article that nicely describes how PDB files of project references can be included in the VSIX package: http://www.cazzulino.com/include-pdbs-in-vsix.html.

Now I would like to do the same, but for documentation XML files that are generated by project references. I see that the XML files are already copied to the output directory of the VSIX project, but how can I make sure that they are added to the .VSIX file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Apparently there is also a "DocumentationProjectOutputGroup" output group. This output group can then be added to all project references in the following way:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultIncludeOutputGroupsInVSIX>
        BuiltProjectOutputGroup;
        DebugSymbolsProjectOutputGroup;
        GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems;
        SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroup;
        BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies;
        DocumentationProjectOutputGroup;
        SatelliteDllsProjectOutputGroupDependencies
    </DefaultIncludeOutputGroupsInVSIX>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ProjectReference>
        <IncludeOutputGroupsInVSIX>$(DefaultIncludeOutputGroupsInVSIX)</IncludeOutputGroupsInVSIX>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add anything file that you want by using `VSIXSourceItem` in your project file or using it from the separate imported project:

```xml
...
<!--You also can invoke this target before GetVsixSourceItems-->
<Target Name="ForceIncludeItems" AfterTargets="GetVsixSourceItems"> 
  <ItemGroup>
    <VSIXSourceItem Include="Path_to_your_xml_file" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Also you can specify [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-select-the-files-to-build?view=vs-2017#specify-inputs-with-wildcards) and functions to select a special files which you want:

```xml
...
<VSIXSourceItem Include="*.xml" Condition="$([System.String]::new('%FileName)').StartsWith('My_start_with_pattern'))"/>
```

More easy but less flexible way is setting `IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer` to true:

```xml
...
<IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer>
```

In this way target will include all items which were included as @DocFileItem (as I know, by default it's only include xml file for vsix project itself).

So to add all xml files excluding suppressed by vsix build package you need to add them manually:

```xml
...
<IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer>

...
<Target Name="AppendNonSuppressXml" AfterTargets="GetVsixSourceItems">
    <ItemGroup>
      <SuppressXml Include="@(SuppressFromVsix->'%(FileName)')" /> <!-- store all suppressed assemblies names to avoid copying their xml files-->
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SuppressAsString>$([System.String]::Join(';', @(SuppressXml))</SuppressAsString> <!-- use to emulate Collections.Contains(item)-->
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- assume that xml files will be received from ReferenceCopyLocalPaths, you can use another source -->
       <VSIXSourceItem 
        Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)"
        Condition="$(IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer) And '%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)' =='.xml' 
         And !($([System.String]::new($(SuppressAsString)).Contains('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.FileName)')))" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: But then we need to specify all XML files manually. Isn't there a way to include all documentation files automatically?

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, but the xml files are still not added to the VSIX after adding <IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeDocFilesInVSIXContainer> to the csproj file.

Comment: @TWT, Are you sure that the relevant assemblies were added to vsix by default (without a custom logic likes `VSIXSourceItem`)? What is the build package that you use to build .vsix? Would be nice if you can append project file to question.

Comment: They are added as project reference. I think this solution only works for documentation files generated by the VSIX itself, as described in the link in the opening post.

Comment: @TWT, I append logic, that append all not suppresed xml files which were added as part of `ReferenceCopyLocalPaths`.